# Woocommerce - Reload checkout after tax calculation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, tax

I want to surcharge special tax based on specific attribute value (billing_company) at checkout page.

Problem is that order details are not automatically recalculated and refreshed. I can refresh the whole page with F5 and then change is visible (8% vat is added to order).

I would like to write a code which will automatically do this for me after user enters specific attribute value on checkout.

Code review:

```
// Add 8% tax for Companies
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_tax_surcharge_for_companies', 10, 1 );
function custom_tax_surcharge_for_companies( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') ) return;

    // Only for Companies (if not we exit)
    if ( 'TEST COMPANY' != WC()->customer->get_billing_company() ) return;

    $percent = 8;

    // Calculation
    $surcharge = ( $cart->cart_contents_total + $cart->shipping_total ) * $percent / 100;

    // Add the fee (tax third argument disabled: false)
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'VAT', 'woocommerce')." ($percent%)", $surcharge, false );

}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use JS to check the value if it changes, then use AJAX to run your PHP function.

Comment: Can you please provide me some code examples?